# Creating a simple form using django and searching a SQL database

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to create a form that will allow users to search a database. The intended language is django. I have created the backend database for a simple student schema, and I will eventually have a stored procedure that takes different parameters, if any of the parameters are provided a search will be done on the database and results returned. For the purposes of this exercise, a simple table will also suffice for searching.

I did some reading up and I have been able to come up with the below, however it feels like a log way from what I am trying to achieve, a prototype can be seen below of what I am trying to achieve. The back end database is SQL server, I have configured the database with django and created the table/tables.

I would also like to understand how to play with stylesheets to create nice looking yet simple pages.

[image]

On my views.py. This is what I have.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from reporting_project.models import sqldbconnection
import pyodbc



def connsql(request):
    conn=pyodbc.connect('Driver={sql server};'
    'server=localhost\DEV2;'
    'Database=django_reporting;'
    'Trusted_connection=yes;')

    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("select student_id, firstname, lastname, fullname, gender , enrollment_date from tbl_students")
    result = cursor.fetchall()
    return render(request, 'index.html',{'sqldbconnection':result})
    
    if 'searchfield' in request.GET:
       searchfield=request.GET['searchfield']
       post=Post.objects.filter(student_search=searchfield)
    else:
        posts=Post.objects.all()
```

For urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',views.connsql)
]
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class sqldbconnection(models.Model):
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    fullname = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1)
    enrollment_date = models.DateField()
```

under template\index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<p>
<div class="jumbotron barber shadow">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-8 offset-2">
<form>
    <div class="input-group">
    <input name ="search_field" type = "text" placeholder ="search"
    <class="form-control form-control-lg"/>
    <div class="iniput-group-append">
    <button class="btn btn-dark btn-lg"> Search </button>
    </div>
    </div>
    </form>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</p>
<title> Database Connection </title>
<body><centre>
<h1> Student Report</h1>
<table border="1">
<tr>
<th>student_id</th>
<th>firstname</th>
<th>lastname</th>
<th>fullname</th>
<th>gender</th>
<th>enrollment_date</th>
</tr>
{%for datadisplay in sqldbconnection%}
<tr>
<td>{{datadisplay.student_id}}</td>
<td>{{datadisplay.firstname}}</td>
<td>{{datadisplay.lastname}}</td>
<td>{{datadisplay.fullname}}</td>
<td>{{datadisplay.gender}}</td>
<td>{{datadisplay.enrollment_date}}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
</centre>
</body>
</head>
```

To create the tables in the database.

```
create table tbl_students
(
student_id int identity(1,1),
firstname varchar(200),
lastname varchar(200),
fullname as firstname +  ' ' + lastname,
gender char(1),
enrollment_date datetime
)


insert into tbl_students (firstname,lastname,gender,enrollment_date)
select 'Sean','Smith','M','12/02/2019'
union all
select 'Dean','Yate','M','01/02/2020'
union all
select 'Dina','Bright','F','11/06/2018'
union all
select 'Florence','Styles','F','10/07/2021'
union all
select 'Mike','Dean','M','09/09/2019'
```

This is what I have so far but the search doesnt work.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean with "doesn't work"? Can you be more specific about what errors you're getting, etc.?

Comment: when I type in any search keyword, it doesn't render the result based on the search field.  I don't get any errors but search doesn't work. Secondly, what I have done so far is not what i want to achieve. It would be good to be able to search by either name, gender or enrollment date.